# Express method-override in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

In a node application at server.js file, what is the difference between use:

```
app.use(methodOverride());
```

or use:

```
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
```

Both of them works. I just want to know if there is any difference between.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: https://github.com/expressjs/method-override

Essentially, it will retrieve your method override from the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header by default. Specifying it makes no difference.

If you were to retrieve your method override from an alternative header, `X-Foo-Bar`, you would use `app.use(methodOverride('X-Foo-Bar'));`.

If you were to retrieve your method override from a query string, `foo=PUT`, you would omit the `X-` prefix, e.g. `app.use(methodOverride('foo'));`